# Implicit declaration of function 'scan_s' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Tags: c, compiler-errors, scanf, c11, tr24731

I've been looking at other questions and none of the solutions have worked so I'll ask my own question.

I'm working on a linux VM and having trouble compiling my code, here are my includes, the error received by the compiler and the code its referring to:

> Error:
>
> linux.c:156:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'scan_s' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ctype.h"

scanf_s("%[^\n]s", filename, maxFilename);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Header for scanf\_s function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836661/header-for-scanf-s-function)

Comment: The [`scanf_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function is pretty new, it was introduced in the C11 standard, and older Linux installations might not have it yet.

Comment: Please show the **exact code**, or a [mcve]. The error suggests that you used `scan_s` instead of `scanf_s`.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf_s` is part of the bounds-checking extension that your compiler may not support.  Use `#ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__` to see if your library/implementation supports it -- if not, fall back to using something like

```
char fmt[16];
sprintf(fmt, "%%%d[^\n]", maxFilename);
scanf(fmt, maxFilename, filename);
```

or

```
fgets(filename, maxFilename, stdin);
if (char *p = strchr(filename, '\n')) *p = '\0';
```

instead.

Note that the `s` in the format string of your example is non-sensical and will not match anything (any `s` will be absorbed by the `%[^\n]` as it is not a newline.

As far as I know, only Microsoft compilers support this extension.