# scanf_s is not included in C11

Tags: c

I'm using Dev-C++ 5.11 and using compiler options to compile to C11. I'm having trouble using the `scanf_s` function. I've tried `<stdio.h>` as well as `<stdlib.h>`.

Is there anything in the standard library that includes this?

Comment: It is not part of the standard - it is a Microsoft extension

Comment: Besides using C++ has better mechanisms from reading stdin

Comment: Still, how can I include scanf_s?

Comment: See [Why didn't gcc implement _s functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724726/why-didnt-gcc-implement-s-functions).

Comment: Why? 1. It is C. 2. Write C++

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Header for scanf\_s function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836661/header-for-scanf-s-function)

Comment: _As with all bounds-checked functions, scanf_s , fscanf_s, and sscanf_s are only guaranteed to be available if __STDC_LIB_EXT1__ is defined by the implementation and if the user defines __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ to the integer constant 1 before including stdio.h._ Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf . Look at the example code they have further down the page.

Comment: @yano [Not quite](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.1.1p3): "It is implementation-defined whether the functions, macros, and types declared or defined in K.3 and its subclauses are declared or defined by their respective headers if `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` is not defined as a macro at the point in the source file where the appropriate header is first included."  Also see [paragraph 1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.1.1p1) and [paragraph 2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.1.1p2).  cppreference.com is better than cplusplus.com, but both have issues

Comment: See also [Do you use the TR 24731 'safe' functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions)

Answer (score 4):

> I'm having trouble using the scanf_s function. I've tried <stdio.h> as well as <stdlib.h>. Is there anything in the standard library that includes this?

`scanf_s()` is part of C since C11.  It is in "Annex K, Bounds-checking interfaces" and it is optional.  Test `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` for its availability.

> An implementation that defines `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` shall conform to the specifications in this annex. C17dr § K.2 2

Comment: @EdHeal True about what OP reports as using, yet rest of question is generic and the question is so tagged.   If Dev-C++ 5.11 with its option set  defines `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`, then proper support for `scanf_s()` is expected.  If not, there may be other ways to get get support, albeit perhaps not the exact same functionality  as MS's `scanf_s()` differs from C11's in some argument types.  In particular, the type of the size argument may differ.

Comment: *In particular, the type of the size argument may differ.*  There's no "may" about it - [per the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.2p4):  "That argument is immediately followed in the argument list by the second argument, which has type `rsize_t` and gives the number of elements in the array pointed to by the first argument of the pair."

Comment: (cont) [Microsoft botches `scanf_s()` pretty spectacularly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l): "The size parameter is of type unsigned, not size_t. Use a static cast to convert a size_t value to unsigned for 64-bit build configurations."  The standard-required type `rsize_t` isn't even mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

`scanf_s` and other Annex K functions are effectively Microsoft-only.

As noted by others, they're optional functions, but the only widely-used development environment that implements them are those from Microsoft, and Microsoft's implementation is non-conforming and not portable.

Per **N1967 - Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm):

> ...
>
> **Available Implementations**
>
> Despite the specification of the APIs having been around for over a
> decade only a handful of implementations exist with varying degrees of
> completeness and conformance. The following is a survey of
> implementations that are known to exist and their status.
>
> While two of the implementations below are available in portable
> source code form as Open Source projects, none of the popular Open
> Source distribution such as BSD or Linux has chosen to make either
> available to their users. At least one (GNU C Library) has repeatedly
> rejected proposals for inclusion for some of the same reasons as those
> noted by the Austin Group in their [initial review of TR 24731-1
> N1106]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1106.txt). It appears unlikely that the APIs will be provided by
> future versions of these distributions.
>
> **Microsoft Visual Studio**
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio implements an early version of the APIs.
> However, the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11
> nor to the original TR 24731-1. For example, it doesn't provide the
> set_constraint_handler_s function but instead defines a
> _invalid_parameter_handler _set_invalid_parameter_handler(_invalid_parameter_handler) function with similar behavior but a slightly different and incompatible
> signature. It also doesn't define the abort_handler_s and
> ignore_handler_s functions, the memset_s function (which isn't part of
> the TR), or the RSIZE_MAX macro.The Microsoft implementation also
> doesn't treat overlapping source and destination sequences as
> runtime-constraint violations and instead has undefined behavior in
> such cases.
>
> As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the
> Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable.

NB the conclusion:  As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable.

So if you use these functions on a Microsoft compiler, you'll wind up writing non-portable code.