# how can i let while loop printf only come once in c?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(void)
    {
        int num;
        int days;
        int week;
        printf("enter a day\n");
        scanf_s("%d\n", &num);
        
    
        while (num)
        {
            week = num / 7;
            days = num - week * 7;
            printf("%ddays are %dweeks, %days\n", num, week, days);
        
        }
    
        if (num <= 0)
    
            printf("your input is wrong\n");
        else
            printf("enter your day again\n");
            
        
            return 0;
    }
```

how can let printf("%ddays are %dweeks, %days\n", num, week, days) only come once then show printf("enter your day again\n"); if my input >0

Comment: If you want it to print only once, move it outside the loop. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If `num != 0`, you have an infinite loop.  It would seem you intend to be updating `num` in the loop, but have forgotten to do so.

Comment: i trying to allow the user to repeatedly enter day values; terminate the loop when the user enters a nonpositive value like <=0

Comment: @asterdis: If you want the user to be able to repeatedly enter input, then you should move the `scanf_s` function call into the loop.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel like that while (scanf_s("%d\n", &num))?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yeah is working right now, but it doesn't allow me to input again

Comment: @asterdis: No, the return value of `scanf` will indicate the number of matched arguments (either `0` or `1`) in this case, but not the value of the converted arguments. I will write a proper answer for you to explain it.

Comment: should i also do else (scanf_s("%d\n", &num)) like that?

Comment: In your question, you state that the loop should "terminate" when the user enters a non-positive value. However, in your posted code, you seem to be attempting to tell the user to "try again", which implies that you do not want the loop to terminate in this case, but rather want the loop to restart. Please clarify this contradiction. Should the program terminate with an error message if the user enters a non-positive value? Or should the user be reprompted for input?

Comment: i want if user input is >=0 then stop the program

Comment: @asterdis: Ok, I will rewrite my answer so that it will stop the program if the input is valid.

Comment: @asterdis: I have now finished rewriting my answer, and have also added lots of additional information on how to prevent the program from misbehaving if the user enters non-digit input.

Comment: @asterdis Note: `scanf_s("%d", &num)` returns 3 different values: `EOF, 0, 1`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzelA Sir i run your program it can't into a loop. for example, if i put an invalid number doesn't allow me enter again even i put valid number

Comment: @asterdis: If you want to discuss my answer, then please post a comment to my answer instead of a comment to your question. Also, please tell me the exact input that you are entering. Additionally. please tell me what you mean by "your program", because I have posted two programs in my answer. It is unclear which one you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is generally not recommended to use the function `scanf_s` if you want your code to be portable to other platforms. It is usually better to use `scanf`. If the only reason you are using `scanf_s` instead is because the Microsoft compiler is telling you that you must do so, then I suggest that you add the line

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

to the very top of your source code file and the Microsoft compiler will accept that you use `scanf` instead.

Also, the line

```
scanf_s("%d\n", &num);
```

is wrong. You should remove the `\n` from the format string. See this question for more information:

[What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19499060/12149471)

If you want your program to continue reprompting the user until the input is valid, then you can use the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        int num;
        int days;
        int week;

        //get input from user and verify it
        printf( "Enter number of days: " );
        if (
            scanf( "%d", &num ) != 1
            ||
            num <= 0
        )
        {
            printf( "Invalid input! Please try again.\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //calculate number of weeks and days
        week = num / 7;
        days = num % 7;

        //print result
        printf( "%d days are %d weeks, %d days.\n", num, week, days );

        //break out of infinite loop
        break;
    }
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Enter number of days: 8
8 days are 1 weeks, 1 days.
```

```
Enter number of days: -3
Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: 0
Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: 14
14 days are 2 weeks, 0 days.
```

However, it is worth noting that this program will get stuck in an infinite loop if the user enters anything else except digits:

```
Enter number of days: abc
Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
Enter number of days: Invalid input! Please try again.
[...]
```

This is because `scanf` will immediately fail without consuming the invalid input, so that the next call to `scanf` will fail for exactly the same reason.

The function `scanf` behaves this way, because it is not designed for user-based line input. Therefore, it would be better to not use this function. It would be better to use the function `fgets` to always read a whole line of input as a string, and then to use the function `strtol` to attempt to convert this input to an integer.

In [this answer of mine to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69636446/12149471), I created a function `get_int_from_user` which uses [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) instead of `scanf` so that it does not have the problem mentioned above. This function will perform extensive input validation and automatically reprompt the user if the input is not a valid integer or cannot be converted to an `int` for some other reason.

If I rewrite your program to use this function, it will look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

//declare function prototype
int get_int_from_user( const char *prompt );

int main( void )
{
    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        int num;
        int days;
        int week;

        //read integer from user
        num = get_int_from_user( "Enter number of days: " );

        //verify that number is positive
        if ( num <= 0 )
        {
            printf( "Invalid input! Please try again.\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //calculate number of weeks and days
        week = num / 7;
        days = num % 7;

        //print result
        printf( "%d days are %d weeks, %d days.\n", num, week, days );

        //break out of infinite loop
        break;
    }
}

int get_int_from_user( const char *prompt )
{
    //loop forever until user enters a valid number
    for (;;)
    {
        char buffer[1024], *p;
        long l;

        //prompt user for input
        fputs( prompt, stdout );

        //get one line of input from input stream
        if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable input error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //make sure that entire line was read in (i.e. that
        //the buffer was not too small)
        if ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL && !feof( stdin ) )
        {
            int c;

            printf( "Line input was too long!\n" );

            //discard remainder of line
            do
            {
                c = getchar();

                if ( c == EOF )
                {
                    fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable error reading from input!\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

            } while ( c != '\n' );

            continue;
        }

        //attempt to convert string to number
        errno = 0;
        l = strtol( buffer, &p, 10 );
        if ( p == buffer )
        {
            printf( "Error converting string to number!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that number is representable as an "int"
        if ( errno == ERANGE || l < INT_MIN || l > INT_MAX )
        {
            printf( "Number out of range error!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that remainder of line contains only whitespace,
        //so that input such as "6sdfj23jlj" gets rejected
        for ( ; *p != '\0'; p++ )
        {
            if ( !isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
            {
                printf( "Unexpected input encountered!\n" );

                //cannot use `continue` here, because that would go to
                //the next iteration of the innermost loop, but we
                //want to go to the next iteration of the outer loop
                goto continue_outer_loop;
            }
        }

        return l;

    continue_outer_loop:
        continue;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the program no longer gets stuck in an infinite loop if I enter something else than digits:

```
Enter number of days: abc
Error converting string to number!
Enter number of days: 8abc
Unexpected input encountered!
Enter number of days: 8
8 days are 1 weeks, 1 days.
```

Comment: @chux: My function `get_int_from_user` treats an end-of-file event the same way as a newline character. See the following line: `if ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL && !feof( stdin ) )`. Therefore, it should work in the situation that you describe.

Comment: enter a day
0
0days are 0weeks, 0ays
your input is wrong
C:\Users\86377\source\repos\assignment2\x64\Debug\item3.exe (process 10244) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .

Comment: the program i run is the first one

Comment: @asterdis: Please specify the desired output as well as the actual output. It is unclear whether the output you are specifying is the desired output or the actual output.

Comment: `scanf_s` is C11, but it is _optional_. Good readings on this are: “[scanf_s is not included in C11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65471315/scanf-s-is-not-included-in-c11)” and “[Why didn't gcc (or glibc) implement _s functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724726/why-didnt-gcc-or-glibc-implement-s-functions)”.

Comment: @ Andreas Wenzel
is the  actual output

Comment: @asterdis: When I enter `0` into the first program I posted in my answer, I get the output `"Invalid input! Please try again."`. Is that not what you want? If you are getting different output, then please verify that you are actually running my posted code and not something else.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel
I check again is the same as your code but still doesn't let me input it again after I enter the first time

Comment: @asterdis: Are you using my posted code exactly as-is? Or did you make modifications to it, for example by changing `scanf` to scanf_s` or by adding `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`?

Comment: @asterdis: Are you able to reproduce the error using [this online interface](https://www.onlinegdb.com/n26Dj60VB)? On that interface, when I press the "Run" button, the code works perfectly, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yes, I didn't make any modifications.

Comment: I suspect that you are not running the code that you think you are running. If you change the line `printf( "Enter number of days: " );` to `printf( "Enter numXXber of days: " );`, does the output of your program change accordingly? Does it print `"Enter number of days: "` or `"Enter numXXber of days: "`? If the output does not change, then my suspicion is correct.

Comment: oh, yeah, but i already save it

Comment: @asterdis: Please answer my question, if you want me to help you. Does the output change to `"numXXber`" or does it stay `"number"`?

Comment: no change stay number

Comment: @asterdis: If changing the `printf` statement of your program does not change the actual output of your program, then you are not running the code that you think you are. Therefore, you are probably using your compiler/[IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) incorrectly. I suggest that you read the output of your compiler closely, in order to determine whether it is printing any error messages. Which compiler/IDE are you using?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel [True, true](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRtB5B6grnA).